# How to configure the Kotlin bytecode inspector?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, bytecode, kotlinc

I want to configure the Kotlin bytecode inspector code in AS 3.5 to use an older version of the Kotlin compiler. Is it possible?

Currently I have a Kotlin 1.1 project, and I'm interested in seeing what the bytecode looked like for certain features when Kotlin 1.1 was new. My problem is that it seems like the Kotlin bytecode inspector always compiles the source code according to the newest version of the Kotlin compiler.

I basically want to reproduce the results of [this](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/exploring-kotlins-hidden-costs-part-1-fbb9935d9b62) experiment.

Incase you can't configure the bytecode inspector to use an old version of kotlinc, is there another convenient way to reproduce the results of the experiment?